# Control on deleting element when using splice in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I write this code for adding or deleting elements in list with `splice`.

When checkbox is checked, add list and when checkbox is unchecked it remove the element from list.

This is my model :

```
export interface Controllermodel {
      controllerName:string;
      controllerDisplayName:string;
      ControllerId:string;
      actionsVM:Actionmodel[];
}

export interface Actionmodel {
      displayName:string;
      name:string;
      metaData:string;
}
```

This is my code :

```
selectedModel: Controllermodel[] = [];
roleId: number;
constructor() {
    this.router.params.subscribe(data => {
      this.roleId = +this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    })

 onChangeValue(event, controllerId: string, actionId: number) {
    var test = this.selectedModel.find(x => x.controllerId === controllerId);

    if (test) {
      var findActionId = test.actionsVM.find(x => x.actionId === actionId);
      const Index = test.actionsVM.indexOf(findActionId);

      if (Index != -1) {
        test.actionsVM.splice(Index, 1);
      } else {
        test.actionsVM.push({ actionEnglishName: null, actionId: actionId, displayName: null });
      }
    } else {
      this.selectedModel.push({
        controllerId: controllerId,
        roleId: this.roleId,
        controllerDisplayName: null,
        controllerFarsiName: null,
        actionsVM: [{
          actionEnglishName: null,
          actionId: actionId,
          displayName: null
        }]
      });
    }
    console.log(this.selectedModel)
  }
```

When I need add this list every thing is ok but when I need to remove with `splice`, I have a problem .

When splice remove the element it set `roleId:0`.

**Can anyone help me fixing this issue?**

Comment: There is an inconsistency in this question. You are saying your having problems with slice but in the code you use splice. They are different functions. Please clarify

Comment: @sinanspd sorry , i edit the question . i mean the `splice`

Comment: your problem statement is not clear. please clarify your problem.